# O que há de errado nesse código js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

A primeira parte do código separa a URL nas `/`

Essa é a URL atual

> www.meudominio.com/categoria/ação

```
var url_atual = decodeURI(window.location.href);
var replace_url = url_atual.replace('http://www.meudominio.com/', '');
var split_url = replace_url.split('/');
```

Agora `split_url` é um array com dois valores `categoria` e `ação`, a função abaixo pesquisa por essa categoria em um outro objeto:

```
var val = split_url[1];
var data = Object.values(livros).filter(function(objecto) { 
    return objecto.categoria.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) > -1 
});
```

Porém `data` não está tendo retorno de resultados, se eu definir manualmente `val = "ação"` a pesquisa encontra todos os resultados relacionados, mas quando o mesmo é passado através da URL, não é encontrado resultados.

**Obs:** Essa problema só ocorre quando há caracteres especiais na URL se eu trocar a categoria por algo como **aventura** ou **romance** a pesquisa encontra resultados, mas quando há algum caractere especial ou letra maiúscula na URL a mesma retorna uma string vazia.

Comment: E se você usar `encodeURI` nos parâmetros ? `encodeURI('ação')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É difícil ter certeza quando não conseguimos simular aqui, seu `return` não deveria ser: `return objecto.categoria.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1` comparando ambos em lower case.

Comment: Adicionando o toLowerCase() junto a val funcionou perfeitamente, estava tão preocupado achando que o problema estava nos caracteres especiais que esqueci de me ligar nisso.

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção é remover a acentuação antes da verificação. Com [ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) ficaria:

```js
var str = "Ação"
str = str.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g,"");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Esse não necessariamente resolve meu problema, mas é um código que vou precisar no futuro kk vlw

Comment: Pois é, pensando bem, daí a string que vai testar o `indexOf` não vai fazer match. Valeu :P

Answer (score 0):

Para Pegar o valor da ação faça desta maneira que fica mais facil

```
var url_atual = decodeURI(window.location.href);
var split_url = url_atual.split('/'); 
val = split_url[split_url.length -1]
```

> [val = "ação"]